# Queue not correctly inserting pointers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, queue

I'm trying to recreate a queue in C++ and I'm having trouble with inserting the pointers correctly. Take a look

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int value;
    Node * next_node = nullptr;
    Node * previous_node = nullptr;
};

class Queue {
public:
    Node * front_node = nullptr;
    Node * back_node = nullptr;

    void insert(int number) {

        Node * NewNode = new Node{};
        NewNode->value = number;


        if (front_node == nullptr) {
            front_node = NewNode;
        }

        else if (back_node == nullptr) {
            back_node = NewNode;
        }

        else if (front_node->previous_node == nullptr) {
            front_node->previous_node = back_node;
            back_node = NewNode;

        }

        else {
            Node * temp_node = new Node{};
            temp_node = front_node->previous_node;
            while (1 == 1) {
                if (temp_node->previous_node == nullptr) {
                    temp_node->previous_node = back_node;
                    back_node = NewNode;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    temp_node = temp_node->previous_node;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    int deque() {

        if (front_node == nullptr) {
            if (back_node != nullptr) {
                int return_value = back_node->value;
                back_node = nullptr;
                return return_value;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        else {
            int return_value = front_node->value;
            front_node = front_node->previous_node;
            return return_value;

        }

    }
};



int main()
{
    Queue queue;
    queue.insert(10);
    queue.insert(9);
    queue.insert(8);
    queue.insert(7);
    queue.insert(6);
    cout << queue.deque() << endl;
    cout << queue.deque() << endl;
    cout << queue.deque() << endl;
    cout << queue.deque() << endl;
    cout << queue.deque() << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

According to the insert function as proceeds front_node is a nullptr so the first node will be inserted there and that comes out correct. Next would be the back node and that comes out fine and dandy. When it comes to the third node I insert the back node pointer into the front node previous pointer and the new node into the back_node pointer. The new node does get placed into the back node but front node->previous_node pointer comes out as a nullptr.

Edit 1: I changed the if from front_node != nullptr to front_node != nullptr and back_node == nullptr. It still doesn't seem to insert into the front_node previous node

Edit 2: I took the advice to rewrite it and now I got the insert function working properly but now dequeing seems to go haywire once on the third deque.

Edit 3: My one last mistake was that instead of front_node->previous_node = back_node, I did front_node = back_node. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Well, you have `if (front_node == nullptr) { do stuff } else if (front_node != nullptr) {do other stuff} else yet more stuff`. Nothing in `yet more stuff` is going to execute, because front_node is either nullptr or it's not, there's no other choices.

Comment: One clue that you're missing something significant: you never set `next_node` to anything. Another useful tidbit: the point of tracking `back_node` is so that you do not need a loop in your insertion function. Try drawing out the queue with a few elements in it, sketch what should happen during an insertion, then rewrite your code with that as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Correct insert method is:

```
void insert(int number) {
    Node *NewNode = new Node{};
    NewNode->value = number;
    if (front_node == nullptr) {
        NewNode->previous_node = nullptr;
        front_node = NewNode;
    }
    else{
        NewNode->previous_node = back_node;    
        back_node->next_node = NewNode;
    }
    back_node = NewNode;
}
```

Here first I check if `front_node` is empty, if it is - `NewNode` is first node, also it last. Else, we should add Node after back_node (`back_node`'s next_node). Don't forget to update `previous_node` and `back_node`'s `next_node`. Then set `back_node` to `NewNode`.

Comment: I still get a nullptr.

Comment: `front_node` is first_node, there is no node before first (I think). It's like last node's `next_node` is nullptr.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another insert using a looping mechanism.

```
void insert()
{
    Node * NewNode = new Node{};
    NewNode->value = number;

    if (front_node == nullptr)
    {
        front_node = NewNode;
        back_node = NewNode;
        return;
    }

    Node* node = nullptr;
    for (node = front_node; node->next_node != nullptr; node = node->next_node);

    node->next_node = NewNode;
    NewNode->previous_node = node;
    NewNode->next_node = nullptr;
    back_node = NewNode;
}
```

Enjoy...:)

Now using the back_node pointer to make this more efficient for sufficiently long queues.

```
void insert(int number) {
    Node * NewNode = new Node{};
    NewNode->value = number;

    if (front_node == nullptr)
    {
        front_node = NewNode;
        back_node = NewNode;
        return;
    }

    Node* node = back_node;
    node->next_node = NewNode;
    back_node = NewNode;
    back_node->previous_node = node;
}
```

That's better---;)